# How to make the "shortcut" for gitlab pages available?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

I have the following project: `gitlab.com/username/project` with a set CI script that generates some artifacts in `public`.

All the artifacts are correctly generated, and I can access my static site at

```
username.gitlab.io/-/project/-/jobs/<job-id>/artifacts/public
```

But when I try to access it with

```
username.gitlab.io/project
```

as stated in the documentation, I get a 404 error.

How to enable this shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

The job must be named `pages` to activate Gitlab Pages:

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - run script
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```